# Перечисления и конструктор

Tags: java

```
public enum Apple {
    PIPO(1), BIBO(2), GITO(3);

    private int price; 

    Apple(int price){
        this.price = price;
    }
    int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
}



   public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Apple apple1 = Apple.PIPO(2);
        System.out.println(apple1);
    }
}
```

В enum Apple определен конструтор и не пойму почему мы пишем сразу перечислениям данные в конструктор именно в ENUM, а не в другом месте при создании объекта допустим как мы это делаем с классами:

```
PIPO(1), BIBO(2) ... // в enum(e), а не вот ниже





 public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Apple apple1 = Apple.PIPO(2); //вот тут
            System.out.println(apple1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: экземпляры enum'а создаются при загрузке класса класс лоадером, сами вы их создать не в силах

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  Извините, не очень понял, можно по подробнее?

Comment: эти конструкторы вызываются автоматически при старте программы, вы не можете вручную создать экземпляр перечисления

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Просто я как допустим делал в классе делал конструктор и переменную и в другом классе где метод мейн я создал экземпляр класса и туда вписывал параметры, а тут сразу конструктор тут, переменная тут и тут же передавать в конструктор нужно параметры в данном примере целые числа, как так?

Comment: да, а что Вас смущает? предопределенные параметры?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если под предопределенными параметрами вы подразумеваете, что мы пишем в enum конструктор и там же определяем для перечислений параметры, то да, предопределенные параметры смущают и я их почему-то понять не могу с логической точки зрения, но я не профи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понимаю Вам не понятен сакральный смысл необходимости в таком инструменте как перечисления (enum), попробую пояснить.

Ваш пример из вопроса, с яблоками ценой, может немного запутать, т.к. цена это переменная в каком-то роде.

Лучше взять например цвета светофора в какой-то игре.

```
enum Color {
    RED, GREEN, YELLOW
}
```

Все компоненты определенного цвета - постоянная.

в 99% случаев Вам нет необходимости иметь 2 разных класса описывающих желтый цвет. В цветовой шкале `rgb` например желтый цвет будет представлен чем то вроде `(255, 255, 0)`.

Соответственно наш `enum` будет иметь какой-то вид:

```
enum Color {

    RED(255, 0, 0), 

    GREEN(0, 255, 0), 

    YELLOW(255, 255, 0);

    int r;
    int g;
    int b;

    Color(int r, int g, int b){
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }

    ....
}
```

Экземпляры нашего перечисления `Color` будут созданы в момент загрузки класса, `ClassLoader`-ом  и никогда не будут скушаны `GarbageCollector`-ом. И Обращаетесь вы к ним как по статической ссылке.

```
Color currentColor = Color.RED;
```

Как-то так, надеюсь Вам хоть чутка стало понятнее =)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь да